# Запуск Joomla в Docker

Tags: joomla, docker, docker-compose

Мне необходимо запускать и работать с существующими сайтами на движке joomla в docker на локальной машине. Но кроме того хотелось бы запускать среду для работы и с другими CMS на машине. У меня установлен Docker и Docker Compose на ubuntu  18.04.

Запускаю контейнеры и заливаю базу. Запускаю сайт локально - выдало 500 ошибку. Убрал .htaccess, выдало - Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: The MySQL adapter mysqli is not available.

Помогите разобраться с проблемой запуска. Подскажите решение.

Ниже привожу содержимое docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
        app:    
                image: php:5.6.39-apache
                container_name: app
                volumes:
                        - ./:/var/www/html
                networks:
                        - default
                ports:
                        - "8100:80"
        db:
                image: mysql:5.7
                container_name: db
                volumes:
                        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
                networks:
                        - default
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bfg_pass
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: bfg_local
                ports:
                        - "9906:3306"
volumes:
        db_data:
networks:
        default:
```

Answer (score -1):

В app добавь в конце depends_on: - db